# Crystal Reports: Count on Conditional on a Sum of Group

Tags: crystal-reports

Co-worker needs a count of items which have an average below a threshhold.

I'm wracking my brain to no avail.  In the back of my mind, I'm hearing that you can't do conditionals on aggregates, and therefore, we can't aggregate the conditionals.

Description is:
Given multiple outage times for different objects in (specific months), Calculate availability.  With Availability, get a count of those objects not meeting threshhold.

OK, sounds simple to me, but my conditions don't, and therefore my count won't.

Currently, she has:

```
Group by Month
  Group by Object
    Records of outage events, in seconds

  Sum (outage, object) in seconds  
  availability = (sec. in month - sum(sec. of outage) ) / (sec. in month)
```

From here, she would like a count of those objects w/ availability below a threshhold.  The conditions don't render against a summary field -- which, in a way makes sense.  CR has to pull back all records to get summaries in a second pass, and it would require a third pass to do logic (and counts) against the summaries.

I'm getting nowhere.  Any ideas?  We might be torqued on this one.

Comment: Add'l comments:  Outage Sum and Availability calcs work fine.  1)  Conditional formula on the aggregate value fails      I don't know if the Contionals on an aggregate are losing scope.    2) Count of the conditional formula fails.       [Any better?]

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this very often, but you're actually a little too specific.  Here's what I understand:

1. Your crystal report is grouped by month, then object.  You have a numeric field you want to sum (let's called it `{outage}`).  You then want to sum `{outage}` and then do some calculations on the sum.
2. To do this in each group footer, use `Sum({Outage},{Object})`. Make sure to put this formula (and any other formulas that are dependent on it) in the group footer.
3. To do this in the report footer, use `Sum({Outage})`.  Make sure to put this formula (and any other formulas that are dependent on it) in the report footer.

Do this help? Am I missing anything?

Comment: PowerUser -- Yes, I am too specific. You should see my posts when I don't have time to edit them down.   ----------     :-( Nobody likes to read my emails at work, either. I hate using the Add Comment here, and I can't embed line feeds - hard to read.